# Showing a "cowsay" fortune in every new terminal session

Tags: bash, scripts, user-profile, fortune

I wish to display a `cowsay` message in every terminal window. The command I use is

```
 fortune | cowsay
```

Any ideas how to make it appear whenever I start a new terminal session?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

- Open the file `~/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc` if it should work globally for all users).
- Add the following at the bottom of the file:

  ```
  if [ -x /usr/games/cowsay -a -x /usr/games/fortune ]; then
      fortune | cowsay
  fi
  ```

Comment: does the -x flag mean "if exists" ?

Comment: Yes, "-x" tests if that file exists and is executable. For more information on the the `test` program see its man page: `man test` (`[ ... ]` is short for `test ...`).

Comment: Works for bash on Windows 10 also!

Comment: added `clear` and then the above command to the end `.profile` file as that is what is called on logins.

Answer (score 8):

BONUS: If you're using `bash` you can make a `~/.bash_logout` file and it will execute that when you log out.  Make sure to have it sleep for a second or so, or you'll never see it.

`cowsay "See you later"; sleep 1`

Comment: wow, thats neat! Ill do it immediately!

Answer (score 7):

I would consider setting a limit to the size of the fortune command requested.

```
fortune -s | cowsay
```

This will produce at most 160 characters. This is a good size for a greeting, anything more than that and long fortunes will flood your terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
fortune | cowsay -f `ls -1 /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | sort -R | head -1` -n
```

This will display a random fortune using a random 'cow'.
There's probably a better way to get a random 'cow', but this works for me just fine.

Comment: For Mac: `fortune | cowsay -f \`ls -1 /usr/local/Cellar/cowsay/3.04/share/cows/*.cow | sort | head -1\` -n`

Comment: Whoa I knew mac was Unix-based, didn't realize it even had cowsay and stuff!!

Answer (score 3):

Better you use .bash_profile because .bashrc is also executed at commands like scp and they will fail silently if there is any output

I found a nice script on pastebin. currently using it.

http://pastebin.com/f0QXTPbt

Answer (score 0):

I am using

`cowsay Welcome to Bash Shell` in .bashrc.

This will be prompt every time when you open the terminal.